# Variadic templates question

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a generic code for comparing std::functions using its target() template method. Here is my non-generic sample code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

static void bar() {}
static void baz() {}

bool cmp(std::function<void()> f1, std::function<void()> f2)
{
  void (**t1)() = f1.target<void(*)()>();
  void (**t2)() = f2.target<void(*)()>();
  return (!t1 && !t2) || (t1 && t2 && *t1 == *t2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::function<void()> f1(bar), f2(baz), f3(bar);
  printf("equal:     %d\n", cmp(f1, f3));
  printf("non-equal: %d\n", cmp(f1, f2));
  return 0;
}
```

This compiles and runs fine with gcc 4.6.1 -std=c++-x . However when I'm trying to compile the following generic cmp function the compiler fails with parse error codes:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

static void bar() {}
static void baz() {}


template<typename Result, typename ... Args>
bool cmp(std::function<Result(Args...)> f1, std::function<Result(Args...)> f2)
{
  Result (**t1)(Args...) = f1.target<Result(*)(Args...)>();
  Result (**t2)(Args...) = f2.target<Result(*)(Args...)>();
  return (!t1 && !t2) || (t1 && t2 && *t1 == *t2);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::function<void()> f1(bar), f2(baz), f3(bar);
  printf("equal:     %d\n", cmp(f1, f3));
  printf("non-equal: %d\n", cmp(f1, f2));
  return 0;
}
```

Error codes are:

```
functional.cpp: In function ‘bool cmp(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>)’:
functional.cpp:11:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
functional.cpp:11:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
functional.cpp:11:52: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token
functional.cpp:11:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
functional.cpp:12:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
functional.cpp:12:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
functional.cpp:12:52: error: expected primary-expression before ‘...’ token
functional.cpp:12:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should possibly be

```
f1.template target<Result(*)(Args...)>()
   ^^^^^^^^
```

and similar for the next line.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! However; this syntax is pretty new for me. Can you give me some info about it's usage?

Comment: @kyku - The compiler has to know that it is a template, otherwise it parses this as `f1.target < Result`, which obviously didn't work. It must know that `< >` is to be part of a template and not part of a comparison.

Comment: @kyku : For more information, see this FAQ: [What is the ->template, .template and ::template syntax about?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#templateprefix)